# Tool that I made randomly freezes sometime after long use. How can i track the issue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I made a tool using windows form in visual studio, that searches for different keywords (linear search) from a long text file. It randomly freezes sometime after clicking on a filter button (says not responding). If I try doing the exact same steps after restarting it, it will work fine.

How can i track the issue? Break points won't help as the program is big and I don't know where should i place them.

Also if you let it remain frozen for sometime, it does work successfully and then start freezing again at the same point.

Comment: What kind of tool? Windows Forms? Console Application? Web Application? Exactly what do you mean, "freezes"? Does it freeze on its own, or do you click something and then it freezes?

Comment: It is Windows form application, basically you add a keyword and click filter and it will show you the lines having that keyword out of the whole text.
The application freezes when i click on the filter button or when i remove it. If i restart the app and perform the same steps again, it doesn't freez

Comment: One suggestion: do you know about `IDisposable`? Does your program use a database, streams, etc? Are you disposing them? Are you trapping exceptions (usually, you should not).

Answer (score 2):

Hook up a performance analyzer (perfmon works if it happens within a few minutes) and watch some important values such as:

- Time spent in garbage collection
- Large object heap size
- Total heap size
- logical thread count
- physical thread count
- disk activity

If none of this points to any obvious problem (such as large object heap fragmentation or leaking references), then you can also *pause* the application in Visual Studio. For instance, run the application using Visual Studio's Run button, and then when your application says `not responding`, you can push Visual Studio's Pause button and open up the thread Window and get an idea of what is causing the problem and what's running at the time the UI thread is blocked for so long that Window's says it's "not responding"

Answer (score 2):

Use a log file (or a UI element on a separate thread, depending on the type of application) to indicate to yourself where you are in the processing of the file when the app stops responding. Run the application repeatedly and look for a pattern related to where the app stops.

- Does the app appear to stop after a certain amount of text has been processed?
- Does the app stop on a certain combination of characters?
- Does the app stop when it tries to process an element with a certain characteristic (such as size or complexity)?

After you've gathered some basic data, you can start adding information to your log that seems to relate to the patterns you're seeing. Write out information such as how much memory is being consumed, etc., to try to narrow down the specific pattern that is causing the crash.

The log file is a way to try to get information about the state of your application, the state of the runtime, and the action that was being taken when the crash occurred.